# Windows driver incorrectly identified network card, now somewhere in System devices

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers

I've just installed a [PCI-E network card](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?model=TG-3468) and when it was installed Windows (7 64bit) found a driver.

I then went into device manager and removed the device and the drivers (perhaps I should have just removed the drivers in hindsight) with the intention of installing the new drivers I had downloaded.

When I scanned for hardware changed within Device manager (after removing it) Windows again detected the device but as unknown.

Attempting to install my downloaded drivers failed, so I told windows to update the driver software online, trying to bring it back to how it was a few moments earlier.

Windows scanned, found a driver but then instead of detecting it as a network adapter I saw the System Devices list get updated instead. I have no idea which one it is.

I've tried removing the card and then installing it again but I now can't get it recognised as a network card.

Is there anyway I can get Windows to see it?

This is my device manager list currently - http://cl.ly/R63p

Comment: You have removed the device from within windows, turned the computer off, removed the device, then restart windows, then reinstalled the device, and then restarted Windows right?

Comment: Yep, no change. I'm assuming it recognised it as the System device again.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a pain in the ass.  In every device under the details tab there is a property called Hardware ID that tells you the vender ID and device ID for example:

HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&**VEN_11D4**&**DEV_194A**&SUBSYS_103C30DC&REV_1004

This devices vender ID is 11D4 and its device ID is 194A.  You must go through each system device and find the one (or ones) with the vendor id of 0cf3 ([source](http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?vendor_search_str=0cf3&vendor_search=Search)).  Cross check the device ID to make sure it's your network card (though it may not be listed).  However, this may not work if Windows thinks the card is a different device.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this. Will give this a go when I'm at my PC next and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be something silly like unzipping the driver file you downloaded first, then just running the installation program.

Comment: Unfortunately there wasn't an executable program, the drivers downloaded are the raw driver files.